# What SIM card should I buy for Canada and the USA

Tags: usa, canada, cellphones

> This question has been marked as a duplicate. While it is very similar to another question, that questions doesn't have answers which specifically solve my problems: i.e., those answers do not recommend a SIM that I can buy in Canada and which will provide me with good-value texts, calls, and data in both Canada and the USA.

I'll be flying in to Victoria, BC at the end of next week, before traveling overland to Toronto and then over to the US; to Buffalo, and then on to the east coast. In total I'll be in North America for just under a month.

I'd like to get a SIM card that gives me data access for my iPhone 6 Plus. Ideally I would buy this in Victoria, and it would then work across Canada and into the US, without charging me roaming fees (or at the least, not charging excessive fees). I'd also like some calling and texting allowance, and preferably the ability to text UK numbers without running up huge charges.

What SIM card should I go for? If I have to I will buy two, one for Canada and another for the US, but I'd rather get one to cover both countries.

Comment: Try signing up for Wind Mobile in Canada and pay for their US Roaming. All in all, it should cost you about 45 dollars a month for unlimited talk, text and data (subject to fair use ofcourse).

Comment: You've edited to say it doesn't provide recommendations for a card to buy in US/Canada. Please refer to our [help] - recommendations are ususally off topic, which is why you won't get that.